# How to get Ruby to retrieve specific data from a YAML file?

Tags: ruby, yaml

First off, I am still a novice Ruby user so this is probably a trivial question but I'm still struggling regardless.
So I have a YAML file set up like so:

```
userA:
    {
        nick: cat ,
        fruit: apple ,
        canDance: true ,
        age: 20
    }

userB:
    {
        nick: dog ,
        fruit: orange ,
        canDance: false ,
        age: 23
    }
```

Assuming that the YAML file has been loaded into Ruby, how would I be able to retrieve specific parts of this file, such as retrieving userA's fruit, or userB's canDance? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read the required information from your YAML like this:

```
require 'yaml'

people = YAML.load_file('the_filename.yaml')

puts people['userA']['fruit']    #=> 'apple'
puts people['userB']['canDance'] #=> true
```

Note: Your YAML file seems to be valid and can be read by the default Ruby YAML parser. But it uses a very special and uncommon syntax. I suggest writing your YAML like this:

```
userA:
  nick: cat
  fruit: apple
  canDance: true
  age: 20

userB:
  nick: dog
  fruit: orange
  canDance: false
  age: 23
```

Comment: Thank you very much, friend! I appreciate it!

Comment: "First of all your example isn't a valid YAML file." – What makes you say that? Can you point to the specific clause in the YAML 1.2 specification that is violated? I am slightly confused because I tested the OP's YAML with several parsers and all were able to parse it, and I also tested it with several validators, and approx. 50% did validate it, while 50% did *not*. But, I have trouble seeing the *exact* violation.

Comment: In particular, [Oren Ben-Kiki's Reference Parser *does* parse it](http://ben-kiki.org/ypaste/data/1620/index.html).

Comment: @JörgWMittag. You made a good point. I just looked into the YAML 1.2 specifications and was surprised to learn that can actually use curly braces and commas to describe hashes. I have never seen that before and this syntax seems to be very rare. But you are right while it uses a very special syntax the syntax looks okay. Perhaps some validators only implement the common syntax? Now I am confused too.

Answer (score 0):

Updated: Your sample data can be parsed as is by Ruby's standard lib YAML, however the curly braces and commas are  not required.

Here is an example with some mixed types added for `hobbies`

#### test.yml

```
---
userA:
  nick: cat
  fruit: apple
  canDance: true
  age: 20
  hobbies:
    - coding
    - tennis
  music:
    production: true
    djing: true
    guitar: true

userB:
  nick: dog
  fruit: orange
  canDance: false
  age: 23
  hobbies:
    - coding
    - ruby
  sports:
    tennis: always
    soccer: sometimes
    running: rarely
```

Use Ruby's [Yaml core lib](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/yaml/rdoc/YAML.html) which you can simply require.

```
require 'yaml'

people = File.load_file 'test.yml'
```

`people` is now an instance of [Hash class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html) which allows you to get the values of keys by calling them inside of square braces like so:

```
people['userA']
```

Now you can dig through the object by chaining keys like this:

```
people['userA']['hobbies']
```

However note that you will get an error if the chain "breaks"

```
people['userB']['sports']['tennis'] # this works
=>"always"

people['userA']['sports']['tennis'] # this will raise
=>NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

Exception is raised because `people['userA']['sports']` returns nil so trying to chain `['tennis']` throws the error.  A useful way to avoid this when digging through a deeply nested hash is to use `.dig`

```
people.dig('userB','sports','tennis')
=>"always"
people.dig('userA','sports','tennis')
=>nil # 
people.dig('userA','music','djing')
=>true
people.dig('userB','music','djing')
=>nil
```

With hashes who's key's are strings you can also string interpolate. Let's say we want to randomly select a user and dig through it we may do something like:

```
people.dig("user#{ ['A','B'].sample }",'music','djing')
```

Comment: "your sample data is not valid YAML" – Can you point to the specific clause in the YAML 1.2 specification that is violated? I am slightly confused because I tested the OP's YAML with several parsers and all were able to parse it, and I also tested it with several validators, and approx. 50% did validate it, while 50% did not. But, I have trouble seeing the exact violation. In particular, [Oren Ben-Kiki's (author of the YAML spec) Reference Parser *does* parse it](http://ben-kiki.org/ypaste/data/1620/index.html).

Comment: "You can see that by testing it in this linter http://www.yamllint.com/" – If I test the OP's YAML with that linter, I get the result: "Valid YAML!" What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes, not sure what I was thinking.  I updated my answer.